# DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set - PlayFramework

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework

I am using java-play-spring template (obtainable here: https://github.com/jamesward/play-java-spring#master )and currently I am trying to switch from the default hibernate db drivers to mysql ones.

I have added an entry to build.sbt:

```
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.12"
```

Then I opened application.conf and changed from

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
```

to:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase"
```

After redeploying my application, I get an error:

```
Factory method [public javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory configs.DataConfig.entityManagerFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is
 org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

I didn't change anything in the basic configuration, so it remains this way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataConfig {

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("models");
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap(new HashMap<String, String>(){{
            put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        }});
        entityManagerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return entityManagerFactory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Play.application().configuration().getString("db.default.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(Play.application().configuration().getString("db.default.url"));
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

Does anyone know what could be the reason of this error? Full error stack below:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private services.BarService controllers.Application.barService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'barServiceImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class configs.DataConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory configs.DataConfig.entityManagerFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:166) ~[play_2.10-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130) ~[play_2.10-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130) ~[play_2.10-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:128) ~[play_2.10-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private services.BarService controllers.Application.barService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'barServiceImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class configs.DataConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory configs.DataConfig.entityManagerFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private services.BarService controllers.Application.barService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'barServiceImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class configs.DataConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory configs.DataConfig.entityManagerFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'barServiceImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class configs.DataConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory configs.DataConfig.entityManagerFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class configs.DataConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory configs.DataConfig.entityManagerFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:601) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory configs.DataConfig.entityManagerFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver$3.run(ConstructorResolver.java:584) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by myself, I just modified dataSource configuration like below:

```
    @Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(Play.application().configuration().getString("db.default.driver"));
    dataSource.setUrl(Play.application().configuration().getString("db.default.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(Play.application().configuration().getString("db.default.user"));
    dataSource.setPassword(Play.application().configuration().getString("db.default.password"));
    return dataSource;
}
```

Wasn't that hard after all, leaving it for future Play newbs.